# Django models RelatedObjectDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-models

i am making an ecom app for Django but when i use a diffrent user i get this error. i think it has something to do with assigning a `Customer` to a `User`, as when i manually create a `Customer` with a `User`.

```
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
User has no customer.
Exception Location: L:\Django\Website\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py in __get__, line 420
Python Executable:  L:\Django\Website\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
```

here is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def store(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0,'get_cart_items':0, 'shipping':False}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    search = request.GET.get('search')
    products = Product.objects.all()

    if search != '' and search is not None:
        products = products.filter(name__icontains=search)

    context= {'products': products, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

...unrelated...
```

here is my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

...unrelated...
```

========================
when i use the method in the code block it doesn't save the extra fields

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to login')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

but when i try this it saves everything except the passwords
forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
        user.save()
        return user
```

views.py is the same.

Comment: Are you sure a Customer exists in the database with the current logged in user?

Comment: @Vincent i have to create a customer for it to work but how would i get it to do that automatically if there is not one made

Comment: I would suggest creating a Customer as soon as a user registers.

Comment: @Vincent could you assist with a link or some code on how to do that

Comment: Can you show me how you currently register users

Comment: Probably something goes wrong with the save method. Why are you overriding it? I don't think thats necessary for those fields. Try removing the save method override. Does it save the password and other fields then?

Comment: if i remove my custom save field then it only saves the default I.E. password and username

Comment: alright thats okay as you might want to refer to a registered user as a customer anyway, so saving the names for the User model is not mandatory. You would rather save those values to the customer model as you can refer to just the customer model then throughout the whole ecom app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217234/discussion-between-vincent-and-connor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use the Customer model as what you refer to as the user throughout the app. Therefore I would keep the save method for the user as default and add the extra fields to the Customer model.

This makes it also easier to later add extra data of the user when registering. The Customer would be created on registering the user. For example:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        user = super().save()
        customer = Customer.objects.create(user=user, first_name=self.cleaned_data.get('first_name'),
            last_name=self.cleaned_data.get('last_name'), email=self.cleaned_data.get('email'))

        return user
```

The Customer model will need a first_name and last_name field instead of name now.
Your current code (store view) will then work as well.